# Can't define an associative array type: opEquals doesn't exist

Tags: d

I can't use non-primitive types as keys for associative arrays; attempting to do so will result in the following error on the line where I define the AA:

```
Error: AA key type MyString does not have 'bool opEquals(ref const MyString) const
```

I first discovered this when using the type `CollisionHandler[Tuple!(TypeInfo, TypeInfo)]` where `CollisionHandler` is an alias for a function pointer type.

However, even the example code from the "Using Structs or Unions as the KeyType" heading under the [Associative array documentation page](http://dlang.org/hash-map.html) fails with the same error:

```
import std.string;

struct MyString
{
    string str;

    size_t toHash() const @safe pure nothrow
    {
        size_t hash;
        foreach (char c; str)
        hash = (hash * 9) + c;
        return hash;
    }
    // opEquals defined here?
    bool opEquals(ref const MyString s) const @safe pure nothrow
    {
        return std.string.cmp(this.str, s.str) == 0;
    }
}

int[MyString] foo; // errors here

void main() {

}
```

Here, `MyString.opEquals` is defined and should have the proper signature, yet the dmd compiler says that it isn't implemented. The fact that this snippet comes straight from the docs makes me suspect it's a compiler bug, but maybe I'm just missing something?

Running DMD under Linux, but the issue also happens under Windows 7. DMD version:

```
$ dmd --help
DMD64 D Compiler v2.066.1
Copyright (c) 1999-2014 by Digital Mars written by Walter Bright
Documentation: http://dlang.org/
...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a case of a misleading error message emitted by the compiler.

The problem is with the `@safe` annotation on the `opEquals` method. In 2.066.1, `std.string.cmp` is not `@safe` - however, the compiler displays the wrong error message. If you rename `opEquals` to something else, e.g. `foo`, you'll get a different error message:

```
test.d(19): Error: safe function 'test.MyString.foo' cannot call system function
'std.algorithm.cmp!("a < b", string, string).cmp'
```

The workaround is to remove `@safe`, or replace it with `@trusted`.

Note that this problem does not manifest in the development version of DMD, so it should be fixed in 2.067.0.